# Excel VBA to Insert a new row if condition meets & fill color where condition met

Tags: excel, insert, macros, row, vba

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRowBelowNegativeEntriesInFGHI()

    Dim lLastColRow As Long
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim lColIndex As Long
    Dim lRowIndex As Long
    Dim bInsert As Boolean
    Dim bIsBalanceRow As Boolean
    Dim vFPos As Variant
    Dim vGPos As Variant
    Dim vHPos As Variant
    Dim vIPos As Variant
    Dim vJPos As Variant
    Dim vKPos As Variant
    Dim vLPos As Variant
    Dim vMPos As Variant
    Dim vNPos As Variant
    Dim vOPos As Variant
    Dim vPPos As Variant
    Dim vQPos As Variant
    Dim vRPos As Variant
    Dim vSPos As Variant
    Dim vTPos As Variant
    Dim sTrigger As String

    For lColIndex = 6 To 10
        lLastColRow = Cells(Rows.Count, lColIndex).End(xlUp).Row
        If lLastColRow > lLastRow Then lLastRow = lLastColRow
    Next

    For lRowIndex = lLastRow - 1 To 2 Step -1
        If UCase(Cells(lRowIndex, 1).Value) = "BALANCE" Then
            'On a BALANCE row
            bInsert = False
            vFPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "F").Value
            vGPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "G").Value
            vHPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "H").Value
            vIPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "I").Value
            vJPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "J").Value

            If vFPos < 0 And (vGPos > 0 Or vHPos > 0 Or vIPos > 0 Or vJPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "F"
            If vGPos < 0 And (vHPos > 0 Or vIPos > 0 Or vJPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "G"
            If vHPos < 0 And (vIPos > 0 Or vJPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "H"
            If vIPos < 0 And (vJPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "I"

            If bInsert Then
                Cells(lRowIndex + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                'Debug.Print lRowIndex, sTrigger
            End If

        End If
    Next
    For lColIndex = 11 To 15
        lLastColRow = Cells(Rows.Count, lColIndex).End(xlUp).Row
        If lLastColRow > lLastRow Then lLastRow = lLastColRow
    Next

    For lRowIndex = lLastRow - 1 To 2 Step -1
        If UCase(Cells(lRowIndex, 1).Value) = "BALANCE" Then
            'On a BALANCE row
            bInsert = False
            vKPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "K").Value
            vLPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "L").Value
            vMPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "M").Value
            vNPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "N").Value
            vOPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "O").Value

            If vKPos < 0 And (vLPos > 0 Or vMPos > 0 Or vNPos > 0 Or vOPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "K"
            If vLPos < 0 And (vMPos > 0 Or vNPos > 0 Or vOPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "L"
            If vMPos < 0 And (vNPos > 0 Or vOPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "M"
            If vNPos < 0 And (vOPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "N"

            If bInsert Then
                Cells(lRowIndex + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                'Debug.Print lRowIndex, sTrigger
            End If

        End If
    Next
    For lColIndex = 16 To 20
        lLastColRow = Cells(Rows.Count, lColIndex).End(xlUp).Row
        If lLastColRow > lLastRow Then lLastRow = lLastColRow
    Next

    For lRowIndex = lLastRow - 1 To 2 Step -1
        If UCase(Cells(lRowIndex, 1).Value) = "BALANCE" Then
            'On a BALANCE row
            bInsert = False
            vPPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "P").Value
            vQPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "Q").Value
            vRPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "R").Value
            vSPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "S").Value
            vTPos = Cells(lRowIndex, "T").Value

            If vPPos < 0 And (vQPos > 0 Or vRPos > 0 Or vSPos > 0 Or vTPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "P"
            If vQPos < 0 And (vRPos > 0 Or vSPos > 0 Or vTPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "Q"
            If vRPos < 0 And (vSPos > 0 Or vTPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "R"
            If vSPos < 0 And (vTPos > 0) Then bInsert = True: 'sTrigger = "S"

            If bInsert Then
                Cells(lRowIndex + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                'Debug.Print lRowIndex, sTrigger
            End If

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I am using the above code to find if there are any negetive value is followed by any positive value in the  column FGHIJ,KLMNO,PQRST of Balance row. In column A there are multiple Balance rows.

The above code is working and it inserts a new row in above Balance when there are any negative value followed by any positive value from left to right. But for the column PQRST (for column 16-20) its not working, I don't know why & what should be the change required in the code for that ?

1. I want to add 2 rows if the condition meets instead of 1 rows in all 3 categorized columns (FGHIJ) (KLMNO) (PQRST)
2. I want to have a word "By Adjustment" in Column A in the first blank added row.
3. I want the portion should be filled in color green for which the condition met.

for example in F6 G6 H6 I6 J6
values are 0 -10 100 0 10

here 2 new row will be added
then F6 G6 H6 I6 J6 should be filled in with color green.

where ever the condition will be meet should be colored with green and two blank row should be inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a sub routine is as complex as your you should simplify be delegating tasks to other sub routines and functions.

```
Sub InsertRowBelowNegativeEntriesInFGHI2()
    Dim lLastRow As Long, lRowIndex As Long
    Dim InsertF As Boolean, InsertK As Boolean, InsertP As Boolean

    lLastRow = Range(Columns(6), Columns(20)).Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For lRowIndex = lLastRow To 2 Step -1
        If UCase(Cells(lRowIndex, 1).Value) = "BALANCE" Then
            InsertF = ShouldInsert(lRowIndex, "F")
            InsertK = ShouldInsert(lRowIndex, "K")
            InsertP = ShouldInsert(lRowIndex, "P")

            If InsertF And InsertK And InsertP Then
                Rows(lRowIndex & ":" & lRowIndex + 1).Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

                Range(Cells(lRowIndex, "F"), Cells(lRowIndex + 1, "T")).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Cells(lRowIndex, 1) = "By Adjustment"
                Cells(lRowIndex, 1).Offset(1) = "By Adjustment"
            ElseIf InsertF Or InsertK Or InsertP Then
                Rows(lRowIndex).Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

                If InsertF Then Range(Cells(lRowIndex, "F"), Cells(lRowIndex, "J")).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                If InsertK Then Range(Cells(lRowIndex, "K"), Cells(lRowIndex, "O")).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                If InsertP Then Range(Cells(lRowIndex, "P"), Cells(lRowIndex, "T")).Interior.Color = vbGreen

                Cells(lRowIndex, 1) = "By Adjustment"
            End If
        End If

    Next

End Sub

Function ShouldInsert(xRow As Long, firstColumnLetter As String) As Boolean
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim bNegative
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Cells(xRow, firstColumnLetter)
    Dim a(4) As Double

    For y = 0 To 3
        If c.Offset(0, y) < 0 Then bNegative = True

        If bNegative And c.Offset(0, y + 1) > 0 Then
            ShouldInsert = True
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next

End Function

Function OldShouldInsert1(xRow As Long, firstColumnLetter As String) As Boolean
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Cells(xRow, firstColumnLetter)

    ShouldInsert = (c.Offset(0, 0).Value < 0 And (c.Offset(0, 1) > 0 Or c.Offset(0, 2) > 0 Or c.Offset(0, 3) > 0 Or c.Offset(0, 4) > 0)) _
    Or (c.Offset(0, 2).Value < 0 And (c.Offset(0, 3) > 0 Or c.Offset(0, 4))) _
    Or (c.Offset(0, 3).Value < 0 And (c.Offset(0, 4) > 0 Or c.Offset(0, 5) > 0)) _
    Or (c.Offset(0, 4).Value < 0 And (c.Offset(0, 4) > 0))

End Function
```

Comment: With your code I found that, 2 green blank rows are being added, but my conditions don't fulfill, I want that if there are any negative values followed by any positive values in (FGHIJ) column or  (KLMNO) column or (PQRST) column. and positive values means more than 0, then only row will insert and in Column A the word "ByAdjustment" should be there.

Comment: I reread your post and adjusted my answer accordingly.  Let me know if it meets all your conditions.

Comment: I have a excel sheet where there are many Balance rows. In Column A there are Demand Collection Balance Rows, where Balance = Demand - Collection.

So there are multiple Balance Rows are there in that sheet. Column (FGHIJ) (KLMNO) (PQRST) are inter related.

I want a macro that if in any Balance row there are negative value in FGHIJ or  KLMNO or PQRST column followed by any positive value a new row will be insert above the balance row.

Comment: for example

1. there is a negative value in F column -100 and positive value in either G or H or I or J column
2. there is a negative value in G column -100 and positive value in either H or I or J column
3.there is a negative value in I column -100 and positive value in either I or J column
4.there is a negative value in I column -100 and positive value in J column

In the above situation a blank row should be insert over the Balance row

If there is any positive value in F column but negative value in G column then row should not be insert

example 40 -100 0 0 0 in FGHIJ column

Comment: Another example 40 -100 20 30 40

Here a new row should be inserted because the negative value is followed by positive values in the column

A new row should insert only if a negative value is followed by a positive value in in F G H I J column serially from left to right.

And Thomas with your code when there are zero in FGHIJ or in KLMNO or PQRST then also two blank rows are being added, and the text byadjustment don't appear.

Comment: Another example 40 -100 20 30 40

Here a new row should be inserted because the negative value is followed by positive values in the column

A new row should insert only if a negative value is followed by a positive value in in F G H I J column serially from left to right.

And Thomas with your code when there are zero in FGHIJ or in KLMNO or PQRST then also two blank rows are being added, and the text byadjustment don't appear.

Comment: I already modified my answer.  If (FGHIJ)  And (KLMNO) And (PQRST) meet the conditions two green rows will be added.  If only one of them meet the condition only 1 row will be added.  If any rows are added the first cell in the row's value = "By Adjustment"

Comment: its not happening, can I send you the sample workbook ?

Comment: Yes please. tommy70458@gmail.com

Comment: mailed you please check

Comment: @JyotirmayaChandrat the code has been updated in my answer.

Comment: Works perfect dear Thomas Inzina, Thank you so so much :-)

Comment: Glad that I could help.  Thanks for the check!